# If element is not in array to file

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently creating a site that will use multiple languages. The way I show the words/sentences is by echoing elements from an array. Right now it works fine, if the element is in the array, but it will show an "Undefined index"-error if it is not. So, I have to add the words to the array all the time, which I really do not want to.

Therefore, I wanted to know, if it is possible to make something like

- if not in array, add 'requested' element to a txt file.

  Or
- If undefined error add to a txt file.

Example of what I am doing right now:

```
<?php echo $lang["Address"]; ?>
//Notice: Undefined index: Address in ...
```

So, if I could get "Address" inserted into a txt file, it would be great. If it is not possible, then I need to add the words/sentences to the array every time I create a new text.

- Maybe something like error logging, but where "Address" is the only thing that is logged?

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: There are many ways to implement localization. Using your way, I would always load the base language and then load over it (merge, not replace) the current language of the user. This way the strings not translated yet are still present in `$lang[]` in the base language. I suppose there is a base language that contains all the strings and (probably partial) translations to other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest translate function should help:

#### function

```
function __translate($name, $currentLang = 'en') {
    $path = sprintf("trans/%s.php", $currentLang);
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        throw new Exception('No file for lang:' . $currentLang);
    }
    $lang = include($path);
    if (isset($lang[$name])) {
         return $lang[$name];
    } else {
         file_put_content($currentLang . '_errors.txt', "\n\r". $name, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

#### 'trans/en.php'

```
<?php

return ['address' => 'Your address'];
```

#### 'trans/de.php'

```
<?php
// we don't have translation for address
return [];
```

#### Use

```
<?php echo __translate["Address"]; ?>
```

Eventually, you can check some libraries for localization.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this.

```
if(isset($lang["Address"]))
{
   echo $lang["Address"];
}
else
{
   //else part
}
```

Comment: I want something to check it by it self. This would not be a good solution because I have a lot of sentences, which I would need to check in the if-statement.

Comment: you can use dynamic index instead of "Address". it checks all of your sentences.

Comment: Can you give an example of that? - Not sure what you mean by dynamic index

Comment: store your sentences to a variable. check that variable in if like.  $sentence = "your sentence"; if(isset($lang[$sentence])){echo $lang[$sentence];}. may be it works.

Answer (score 0):

@Maitray Suthat is right. Here's a shorter version of the IF.

```
echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit '.(isset($lang["Address"])?$lang["Address"]:'').', consectetur adipiscing elit.';
```

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Even shorter:

```
echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit '.($lang["Address"]??'').', consectetur adipiscing elit.';
```

Comment: With this I have to edit all the places I echo from the array. What I am looking for is a method where I do not have to do that.

Comment: You could iterate over the array before outputting it's contents. if anything is empty or !isset then replace it with an empty string... You'd have a issue with double-spaces, but dom-rendering could take care of that.

Comment: & Thanks very much for the edit @Evert It's the Null Coalesce Operator, correct? https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary There's an extra closing parenthesis. I'd edit it but would like you to keep the credit on this comment. Was it a typo or is that correct syntax?

Comment: @admcfajn totally a typo and you knew it =) appreciate it though. `??` is my favourite operator now ;)

Comment: I think it's soon to become mine as well. Thanks again :)